# When I pause a song on my iPod classic it forces me to listen to every song by that artist, how can I fix this?

Tags: ipod-classic

If I am listening to a playlist and pause a song in that playlist my iPod will not let me get out of that playlist I am forced to listen to every song on the playlist and once it is done then I am able to navigate through the iPod. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Restart or reset the ipod. This should not happen.